# python coding sum the rows and columns of a grid

Tags: python

I am trying to use a spread sheet format in python coding.
Trying to teach my junior high school students how to read a table from a matrix.txt file and produce a set of rows and columns. I then want them to see if the sum of each column matches the sum given and same for the rows.
Here is what I am putting in the matrix.txt file

```
3 3
7 2 5 14
6 3 1 10
3 9 8 20
16 14 14
```

Here is the code I have constructed so far but I just cant get my head around how to get the program to calculate the sum of each rows first three (number of rows) integers.
Hope someone can help.

```
k=[]
with open('matrix.txt') as f:
  grid_data = [i.split() for i in f.readlines()]
for el in grid_data[0:]:
  for num in el[0]:
     k.append(num)
row=int(k[0])
for i in range(1,row):
  for el in grid_data[i]:
    print(sum(el[0:row-1]))
```

If there is a better way to solve this please let me know. It is a past UNSW coding comp question from 2014. I would love a cool way to analysis tables or grids in python.

Comment: are you allowed to use other libraries ike numpy/pandas?

Comment: In addition to @gabhijit's remark on using numpy: if there is time, first each them this way (pure Python), then show how it can be done much simpler and more elegant using numpy. Because for any type of calculations involving arrays / spreadsheet style, numpy or pandas will almost always be a better than option, so it's good if people know about it.

Comment: The students are using the "Grok" interface screens for python and for some reason I can't import numpy? Do you know why - could it have another import name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy is total overkill for such a simple problem, and would require that you dump a whole bunch of extra background learning on young students.

I generally don't like spoon-feeding, but there are too many elements to a pythonic solution to readily explain in prose, so here's the code:

```
with open('matrix.txt') as f:
    # Skip dims because redundant.
    f.readline()

    # Convert to int as we read.
    grid = [map(int, i.split()) for i in f]

# Define convenience vars (also for efficiency - rows is evaluated twice).
rows = grid[:-1]
totals = grid[-1]

# Verify row totals.
for (r, row) in enumerate(rows):
    assert sum(row[:-1]) == row[-1], 'row {}'.format(r)

# Verify column totals.
for (c, total) in enumerate(totals):
    assert sum(row[c] for row in rows) == total, 'col {}'.format(c)
```

**EDIT:** [Blue reminded me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30825592/9990) of a very nice pythonic trick for transposing an array.  The end result is more elegant:

```
# Replace convenience down with…

# Verify row totals.
for (r, row) in enumerate(grid[:-1]):
    assert sum(row[:-1]) == row[-1], 'row {}'.format(r)

# Verify column totals.
for (c, col) in enumerate(zip(*grid)[:-1]):
    assert sum(col[:-1]) == col[-1], 'col {}'.format(c)
```

The only caveat (and the reason I left the original intact) is that it might explode the average junior high brain. Use with caution.

Comment: Kicking myself - sum(row[:-1]) seems so easy!!! I am still getting an error using this though - error reads that 'map' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: @user3864194: Not sure why. I ran the code against your input and it worked as-is. Actually, to be entirely truthful, I had an em-dash there that broke the python, so I just replaced it now with a regular hyphen, but that wouldn't explain your problem.

Comment: @user3864194: I just corrected and simplified the **EDIT:** code (tested too).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a problem with matrix.txt file since you don't have the same number of elements in each row. I assume square matrix here, like this

```
3 3 0 0
7 2 5 14
6 3 1 10
3 9 8 20
16 14 14 0
```

Then a possible solution using list comprehension and the concept of transpose (which might be a pedagogical good thing for students) is this

```
with open("matrix.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# convert matrix data to integers

matrix = [[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in content]


# sum the rows

print('sum of lines')

for line in matrix:
    print(sum(line))

# transpose the matrix

transpose_matrix = list(zip(*matrix))

# do the same with the transposed matrix

print('sum of rows')

for line in transpose_matrix:
    print(sum(line))
```

The result is this:

```
some of lines
6
28
20
40
44
sum of rows
35
31
28
44
```

Comment: The OP doesn't just want sums for each line (and the first line is matrix dims (and not necessary)), but +1 for the transpose trick. Kicking myself for not thinking of it in my answer. You don't need `list(zip(*matrix))` though; `zip(*matrix)` suffices.

Comment: @ Marcelo Cantos Thank you! You are right about zip(*matrix) and in fact your conversion to int is much nicer :) please feel free to update your answer with what you find good in mine if you want, so that a better answer is available!